# HP Recovery Manager

Tags: backup

Anyone had any experience with HP's Recovery Manager? I backed everything up as suggested, reformatted everything, then ran the recovery manager which copied the data to a folder named `System Recovery`. Apparently, that's not the same as a Windows Backup. =/ Now what?

Is it safe to just copy the files from Windows Backup straight to my drive C? (Recon I won't be able to copy some parts, especially the Windows folder, but the others could work)

EDIT:
Specs are: Notebook, Windows 7. Stored the backup in an external hard drive. In the same folder there's a RecoveryMgr executable which I assume was the Recovery Manager. No Restore.exe

Comment: Updated question with details

Comment: What kind if files (file extension) are in the System Recovery folder?

Comment: The System Recovery folder had the uncompressed files in their original file formats. Before I ran RecoveryMgr from the backup disk, they were had a ".WIM" extension.

Comment: I see you found your answer on your other question...http://superuser.com/questions/336605/overwrite-your-windows-folder-with-a-backed-up-copy

Comment: Yeah. Apparently, I misunderstood what a backup does (first-time I've ever had to do this). I think your last comment to my other question is relevant to this one. You could post that as an answer here.

Comment: I am working with HP on the consumer forums currently to get some better documentation for recovering backups made when you use recovery manager, might take some time. My comment over there does not answer your question here, I will post an answer when I have more relevant information.