# Overwrite your Windows folder with a backed up copy

Tags: windows, backup, restore, oem

Currently attempting to [restore a backup](https://superuser.com/questions/335548/hp-recovery-manager). I'm left wondering whether HP intends for me to just overwrite my whole C: drive with the contents from the backup. Overwriting the Users folder, Application Data and Program Files won't be a problem. What I don't know is what to do with my Windows folder. That prolly contains all my Windows Updates, drivers and stuff necessary for the apps in my Program Files to work. I don't know the details and instinct tells me that this is stupid but I'd like to know the implications of doing so anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just retrieve the files from your documents folder - leave everything else alone. You will have to re-run the updates and re-install applications.

Just replacing those folders with the backup wouldn't getting you up and running again... it would break the install.

The OS files are protected anyway, you would have to boot into a Windows PE disc of some sort or a life Linux disc...

Comment: Awww. That sucks. I was half-hoping there would be some magical software that would fix everything for me.

Comment: Don't expect anything as such. You may consider a clone of your drive instead from now on, which will restore everything to the last working state. Though you may not have the updates, still you will have all the installed programs at the time of cloning.

Comment: I believe later versions of Recovery manager backup do a better job of restoring data and settings using "restore.exe" Use HP Support Assistant on the start menu to install the latest version of the Recovery Manager software. Any personal programs you install will have to be reinstalled after HP recovery is performed.

Answer (score 1):

It reads as if you backed-up with windows backup and then restored your machine to factory settings with HP System Recovery, this will leave you out of date with the hp and windows updates and any programs installed after the factory install.

1. You can update by clicking Windows and HP updates, they will update the drives and patches,it could take a while.
2. You can then re-install programs you had installed like Microsoft office. All the trial offers should be there again.
3. Update again.
4. Then you can return your data to Documents, Video, Music, etc.  You can copy directly from the backup file to the library/folder you need them in. Click on Edits ‘Copy Folder to’ or just highlight then copy and paste into library.

#### Some Basic Recovery info

- HP System Recovery will return your machine to the original factory state. The same is true for your Hp Recovery discs you may have made just after  purchase.
- Your Windows backup will restore your files data, etc to the state at the time of the backup but could require some updates that where not present at the setting of factory conditions. Safest to copy data after updates.
- A Windows System Image Backup would have restored you to the state of your machine at the time of the system backup.

Windows System Image Backup – Control Panel to  System and Security  to  Backup and Restore
Then create a System Repair disc or a System Image.

- Information from windows 7 - help and support ‘backup’

> If you're using Windows Backup to back up your files, you can have a
> system image created each time your files are backed up. By default,
> this system image will only include the drives required for Windows to
> run.
>
> You can create a system image, which contains a copy of Windows and
> copies of your programs, system settings, and files. The system image
> is then stored in a separate location from the original programs,
> settings, and files. You can use this image to restore the contents of
> your computer if your hard disk or entire computer ever stops working.

Hope all works out ok.

Comment: Wait. Which one's the Windows System Image Backup?

Comment: re worded from 3]. down

Comment: Oh do clean it up. It's quite informative. It's prolly too late for me at this point but helpful all the same.